# Web API Stream file from Azure Storage with range support

Tags: azure, azure-storage, asp.net-web-api

I have Azure Storage account with many media files.

I have Azure Website that streams media files directly from Azure Storage containers (public container). Azure Storage account supports range headers.

I want to create Web API controller that will shield direct links to Azure Storage and still support streaming (range headers)

Azure Storage Client Library has method DownloadRangeToStreamAsync() which I think has to be used. It has offset and length parameters.

Does anyone know how to retrieve these values in Web Api?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use shared signature urls to expose your azure storage account in controlled ways, see: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/net/shared-access-signature-part-1/

Comment: @Polity Thanks, I will consider that, however I need to route all outgoing traffic through Azure Website as per requirement. We use log analyzer that currently has no knowledge of file traffic, only request counts.